# filter() function and list comparison

Tags: python

I have a list in python like `l=('A','1,''B','2','C','3,''D','4')` and i need to filter out the value of A,B,C,D so i wrote a code like follow

```
list(filter(lambda x:x.isalpha(),l))
```

then returned `['A', 'C']`

it did't return value B and D so i thought it was some thing i don't know about python filter function then i wrote it in list comparison like follows

```
[i for i in l if i.isalpha()]
```

but the strange thing is it also return the `['A', 'C']` so every time what happen to the value B and  D

Any one can explain me how to filter all alphabetic values out?

Comment: your list has a typo: `'1,''B'` is a sole element. Same thing for 3,D. `l=['A','1','B','2','C','3','D','4']
print(list(filter(str.isalpha,l)))
` gives the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're malforming the list, it should be:

`l=('A','1','B','2','C','3','D','4')`

Notice the commas

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes i got it thanks

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see your question was answered.